# Вопрос по философии WPF

Tags: wpf

Всем привет. В технологии WinForms основная логика приложения заключалась в обработчиках событий. Насколько уместно в технологии WPF с точки зрения философии заключать логику в обработчиках или вместо этого лучше использовать команды?

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле у хорошего программиста логика **НИКОГДА** не заключается в обработчиках событий. В том числе и в WinForms. Что касается WPF, то использование обработчиков там вполне допустимо в ряде случаев, однако же исходя из принципа MVVM рекомендуется использовать команды как более гибкий и удобный инструмент для реакции на действия пользователя и события приложения. Команды в отличие от обработчиков позволяют определять, может ли команда быть исполнена (с отображением этого на элементе - скажем, кнопка, команда которой не может быть выполнена, будет неактивна), позволяют привязать одну и ту же команду  к разным способам ее выполнения (скажем, одно действие может быть выполнено нажатием на кнопку, комбинацией горячих клавиш, выбором пункта меню или нажатием иконки на панели)

В идеале вся обработка тех или иных действий должно строиться именно на командах, а соответствующий cs-файл для xaml должен быть по возможности пустым.

Comment: > Что касается WPF, то использование обработчиков там вполне допустимо в ряде случаев

Представим две ситуации:

Ситуация 1.

При нажатии на определенную кнопку или при выделении строки в DataGrid я хочу отобразить скрытие от глаз пользователя контролы. Уместно ли в такой ситуации использовать обработчики или в WPF все делается по другому?

Ситуация 2.

При выделении строки в DataGrid необходим отобразить данные из выделенной строки в других элементах управления, например, TextBox. В WinForms все это делается в обработчиках, как подобная ситуация правильно решается в WPF?

Comment: я не эксперт в области WPF, но насколько я знаю обе ваши задачи вы можете выполнить на командах. Говоря "допустимо в ряде случаев" я имел в виду, что в случае написания какого-нибудь хелло-ворлда ззаморачиваться с командами не обязательно. Однако философия WPF отдает предпочтение командам. И напоследок - логика в обработчиках событий - есть адское зло, за которое в аду заготовлен отдельный котел с кипящим говном (однако это не говорит о том, что обработчики не нужны)

Comment: В данном случае под "логикой в обработчиках" я понимаю вызов в них методов неких классов, в которых и сосредоточен весь функционал.

Допустим при нажатии на кнопку, у нас вызывается некий метод. Перед тем, как этот метод сможет выполнить возложенную на него работу, ему нужно передать значения (например, введенные пользователем в разные контролы), которыми он сможет оперировать. В случае WinForms и их обработчиков, передать в данный метод значения из контролов не проблема. Но как подобное реализовывается с помощью команд при этом чтобы это было верно с точки зрения идеологии WPF?

Comment: То, что вы хотите,  осуществляет с помощью привязки данных. Ваша Viewmodel  имеет некие свойства, которые привязываются к тем или иным элементам управления, и уже в коде вы можете получать данные с View, читая эти свойства. На порядок удобнее чем в древнем Winforms

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите. Правильная философия — это разделение данных, бизнес-логики и представления. Для WPF обычно используется паттерн MVVM (но он, строго говоря, не обязателен).

Ваша программа должна по идее делиться на 3 уровня.

1. Уровень модели представляет объекты, близкие к вашей предметной области. Они ведут себя не зная о существовании бизнес-логики и тем более UI.
2. Бизнес-логика — это часть программы, отвечающая за реакцию на события, а также приводящая модель и UI «в движение». Сюда же относится представление данных в удобном для вывода виде. Этот уровень в MVVM называется View Model.
3. UI. Это чистый уровень представления, не знающий ничего о модели, и как можно меньше о view model.

Давайте смотреть, что должно произойти, если юзер нажмёт на кнопку.

Если кнопка есть на самом деле запрос на какое-то действие, которое влияет на логику программы, то этот запрос должен перейти во view model. Для этого удобнее всего сделать так: view model предоставляет команду, которую UI-layer забиндит к кнопке. Таким образом, кнопка непосредственно вызывает команду из view model.

Если же кнопка лишь влияет на состояние UI, то вполне возможно, что команда — overkill, и нужную реакцию вполне можно обеспечить обработчиком событий.

Ни тот, ни другой путь не является обязательным, делайте так, как вам удобнее, ну или так, как получается. В любом случае, решение о том, что относится к UI, а что — к бизнес-логике, принимает архитектор проекта (то есть, вы). Например, если кнопка переключает направление сортировки списка, это может быть и чистое изменение флага в UI, а может быть и новый SQL-запрос к базе данных.

Comment: На счет разделения по слоям все понятно. Здесь вопросов у меня нет. 

Объясню ситуацию - есть некая ViewModel, которая отображается пользователю. Предположим ViewModel отображает данные некой персоны класс Person. Сам класс Person помимо простых типов, включает себя поля, являющиеся сложным типом, например класс Address.

Comment: Теперь вопрос. Допустим пользователь захотел добавить в БД новую персону, кликнул на кнопку - отобразилась форма добавления, содержащая множество полей, которые ему необходимо заполнить. Следовательно, он ввел необходимую ему информацию и нажал на кнопку Добавить. Так вот - если я все cделаю в стиле WinForms т.е. подпишусь у кнопки Добавить на событие Click, в котором считаю введенные пользователем в контролы данные и затем эти данные сохраню в БД. Будет ли это противоречить идиологии WPF и паттерну MVVM?

Comment: P.S. Так же мне не понятно как подобное реализуется с помощью команд. Допустим перед тем как передавать введенные пользователем данные на сохранение, я всегда могут проверить их на корректность, проверить заполнены ли нужные поля и т.п. Отмечены ли соответствующие CheckBox, если это требуется. И уже потом, если все это удовлетворяет мои требованиям - я сохраняю данные. Как подобное сделать с командами не ясно!

Comment: @sp7: Смотрите. Для создания формы добавления бизнес-логика создаёт default-ную VM-персону. Отображаемая форма редактирования редактирует эту персону. К кнопке прикреплена команда, которая VM-персону превращает в модельную персону, и командует модели добавить новую персону в базу.

«Собирать» персону по нажатию кнопки не требуется.

---
В WPF валидация обычно происходит при Binding'е, то есть, всё время, а не запускается при нажатии на кнопку. [Ссылка](http://bit.ly/1kg7pIK).