# MVVM и WPF

Tags: wpf

Обращаюсь к знающим.

- Обязательно ли при разработке WPF приложения придерживаться паттерна MVVM, является ли данный паттерн стандартом дефакто для данного типа приложений?
- Подразумевается ли по умолчанию, что когда вам говорят разработайте приложения на WPF ожидают что оно будет реализовывать данный паттерн?

Comment: > А по-другому и не выйдет. Другое дело, что этот метод делает дальше: пытается реализовать бизнес-логику в OnClick или корректно сообщает VM-layer'у и завершается

Как сейчас сделано у меня. Например, есть некая кнопка, которая сохраняет изменения в БД. К этой кнопке прикручена команда (метод, который вызывается при команде расположен в codebehind xaml окна), в которой собственно и вызывается метод, которому и передаются данные, для сохранения.

Comment: Смущает меня собственно вот что во всем этом деле. Для того чтобы корректно сохранить данные мне нужно знать как взаимодействует с интерфейсом пользователь. Приведу простой пример. Например, в гриде выводится список пользователей. Далее юзер выделяет в гриде нужную строку, которая представляет пользователя. Затем в других элементах управления вносит какие изменения. После чего жмет сохранить. Следовательно, для того чтобы внесенные юзером изменения закрепились за конкретным пользователем, нужно знать какой пользователь выделен выделенным гриде.

Comment: Для того чтобы узнать что за пользователь выделен в гриде, я обращаюсь к данной гриде и получаю выделенную строку. Далее эта полученная строка используется в методе, который вызывается командой.

Comment: Вот собственно такой способ получения выделенной строки или еще какой-то информации мне и не нравится. Так ли нужно узнавать в WPF узнавать строку, которая выделена?

Answer (score 3):

Cудя по этому и [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/350757/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8-wpf) вашим  вопросам создается впечатление, что вы либо боитесь или за что-то не любите MVVM, во всяком случае вы зачем-то хотите избежать основных (и, надо сказать, удобных) парадигм и правил разработки с помощью WPF. В рамках WPF MVVM является паттерном "по умолчанию", то есть наиболее удобным, логичным и правильным способом организации приложения. Разумеется, никто не запрещает писать WPF-приложения в стиле WinForms, и при определенной сноровке это будет иметь успех, но все же выглядеть это будет выглядеть как забивание гвоздей микроскопом. WPF предоставляет богатый набор возможностей для разработки именно в рамках MVVM (это и привязки всего чего только можно, и обсуждавшиеся ранее команды и декларативный xaml, способный взять на себя гораздо больше, чем View в WinForms и многое другое), и не использовать эти возможности было бы не самым оптимальным решением.

Подводя итоги:

> Обязательно ли при разработке WPF приложения придерживаться паттерна MVV?

пожалуй не прям уж строго обязательно, но все же желательно, поскольку удобно.

> M, является ли данный паттерн стандартом дефакто для данного типа приложений?

да

> Подразумевается ли по умолчанию, что когда вам говорят разработайте приложения на WPF ожидают что оно будет реализовывать данный паттерн?

не стану говорить за всех за всех, но да, обычно подразумевается в том числе и это. Скажем, если соискателю дают подобное  тестовое задание при устройстве на работу, то потенциальный работодатель скорее всего будет неприятно удивлен, если увидит "WPF в стиле WinForms", справедливо сочтя, что соискатель плохо понимает принципы разработки с помощью WPF

Comment: Дело в том, что до этого я с WPF не работал вообще. А тут возникла срочная необходимость написать приложения используя WPF. С данным паттерном я не знаком, да и к тому же сроки поджимают разбираться во всех этих привязках и командах. Есть недопонимание как эта связка между собой работает. Вот поэтому и весь в раздумьях как быть.

Comment: Кроме того, просматривая примеры в интернете, видел что метод, который вызывается при срабатывании команды, так же размещают и codebehind xaml формы. Это нормальная практика?

Comment: @sp7: Срочно = плохо. Если вы хотите написать быстро и на тяп-ляп, пишите как пишется, но не жалуйтесь, что будет много багов, а поддержка превратится в кошмар. Если хотите написать правильно, освойте MVVM, и да, будет медленнее.

Мой совет — если вам нужно будет в будущем поддерживать этот код, пишите сразу правильно. Если вам поддерживать код не надо будет, пишите как получается, только после сдачи заказа поменяйте номер телефона и email.

Comment: @sp7: А по-другому и не выйдет. Другое дело, что этот метод делает дальше: пытается реализовать бизнес-логику в OnClick или корректно сообщает VM-layer'у и завершается.

Comment: > А тут возникла срочная необходимость написать приложения используя WPF

ну если вы так неосмотрительно согласилиь на работу, которую вам сложно выполнить быстро и правильно, то могу лишь посочувствовать. За пару часов вы технологию к сожалению не изучите

Comment: Кто бы еще спрашивал моего желания. Разнарядка сверху. В принципе, данное приложение раньше было на WinForms т.е. многое уже есть БД, модель. Дело как говорится за "малым", но вот на этом малом и встал.

Comment: Как я понял в WPF логика из обработчиков переносится во ViewModel. Следовательно мне не понятно во что, как я в этой ViewModel буду узнавать что пользователь ввел в некий элемент управления или какую строку в DatGrid выделил, ну и дургие подобные вещи?

Comment: >как я в этой ViewModel буду узнавать что пользователь ввел в некий элемент управления или какую строку в DatGrid выделил, ну и дургие подобные вещи?

привязка данных

Comment: >Кто бы еще спрашивал моего желания. Разнарядка сверху

тогда вы как минимум праве спросить, а почему вам дают работу вне вашей компетенции, да еще и требуют сделать ее за сжатые сроки. Да еще и (уверен) не доплачивают за это